# Get structured output with Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm just starting to use scrapy and this is one of my first few projects. I am trying to scrape some company metadata from https://www.baincapitalprivateequity.com/portfolio/ . I have figured out my selectors but I'm unable to structure the output. I'm currently getting everything in one cell but I want the output to be **one row for each company**. If someone could help with where I'm going wrong, it'll be really great.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import BainpeItem


class BainPeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Bain-PE'
    allowed_domains = ['baincapitalprivateequity.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.baincapitalprivateequity.com/portfolio/']

    def parse(self, response):

        items = BainpeItem()

        all_cos = response.css('div.grid')

        for i in all_cos:
            company = i.css('ul li::text').extract()
            about = i.css('div.companyDetail p').extract()

            items['company'] = company
            items['about'] = about

            yield items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just yield each item in the for loop:

```py
for i in all_cos:
        item = BainpeItem()
        company = i.css('ul li::text').extract()
        about = i.css('div.companyDetail p').extract()

        item['company'] = company
        item['about'] = about

        yield item
```

This way each item will arrive in the pipeline separately.